# How to create a breakpoint using ollydbg for a winApi function call, e.g. a breakpoint for a GetDigiItemA function call?

Tags: winapi, reverse-engineering, breakpoints, ollydbg, cracking

Ollydbg v.1 or v.2
I mean the types of breakpoints that could be set up in SoftIce during the program execution, e.g. getDigiItem, setDigiItemA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Go to the function in question: Press Ctrl+G => `GetDlgItemTextA` => OK
- Set breakpoint: Press F2

To see the list of active breakpoints and disable/remove them, check the breakpoints window (Alt+B).

If you are using the Command Bar plugin ([for OllyDbg1](https://tuts4you.com/e107_plugins/download/download.php?view.40) / [for OllyDbg2](https://tuts4you.com/download/3405/)), you can also write e.g. `bp GetDlgItemTextA` in the command bar.

For OllyDbg1, there is also a useful plugin that adds a menu with often-used breakpoint locations, among a multitude of other features: [IDAFicator](https://tuts4you.com/download/2058/).

See also https://hydrasky.com/network-security/breakpoint-in-ollydbg-part-1/